# Matplotlibwidget in QT gui graph update

Tags: python, matplotlib, qt4

I'm new in Python and I want to developp a GUI program.
I have installed pythonxy and I have developped a QT4 GUI that I have transformed in py with pyuic4.

In my program, I would like to update the mplwidget with new variables when I click on the button. I would like to update only the widget without restart the ui. How can I modify the solution below in order to update only the widget.

Thank you very much for your help and indications

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from matplotlibwidget import MatplotlibWidget
import numpy as np

global y
global x
x=[1,2,3]
y=[1, 2, 1]

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.mplwidget = MatplotlibWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.mplwidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 150, 400, 300))
        self.mplwidget.setObjectName("mplwidget")
        self.mplwidget.setFocus()
        self.mplwidget.axes.plot(x,y)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow) 
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")        

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.plot)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def plot(self):   
        global y
        global x
        x = [2,3,4]
        y = [2,2,1]
        self.replot()

    def replot(self):
        Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `matplotlibwidget`, so there may be an easier way to do this, but you can grab the `Axes` object and do what ever you want to it:

```
def replot_(self, x, y):
    # plot the data and keep a reference to the `Line2D` object
    ln, = self.matplotlibwidget.axes.plot(x, y)
    # force the canvas to re-draw, 
    # matplotlibwidget may provide more direct access to the canvas
    self.matplotlibwidget.axes.figure.canvas.draw()
    return ln
```

Comment: I found the solution by using PlotCanvas. Thank your very much for your reply

Comment: @user3052784 Not sure what `PlotCanvas` is.  If this answer solved your problem then accept it, if it did not, then write what _did_ solve your problem as an answer and the accept you own answer.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that the canvas.draw() method is not thread-safe. If you wish to update your plot from another than the GUI thread, you will need to invoke it via a signal-slot mechanism.